Understanding Unexpected Page Faults in a Memory Touch Program on Linux
I wrote a small C program to allocate a large memory region, touch one byte in each 4 KiB page, and print statistics about page faults. The goal is to understand how Linux handles memory allocation and page faults. Here is the program:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

static unsigned long
clamp(const long current_faults, const unsigned long touches)
{
  if (touches > (unsigned long) current_faults) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (unsigned long) current_faults - touches;
}

static void
print_4kib_page(const void * const address)
{
  const unsigned long number = (unsigned long) address;
  printf("%6lu|", number >> 48);
  printf("%4lu|", (number >> 39) & 0x1FF);
  printf("%4lu|", (number >> 30) & 0x1FF);
  printf("%4lu|", (number >> 21) & 0x1FF);
  printf("%4lu|", (number >> 12) & 0x1FF);
  printf("%5lu| ", number & 0xFFF);
}

int
main()
{
  const unsigned long page_size = 4096;
  const unsigned long page_number = 4096;
  const unsigned long bytes = page_size * page_number;

  char * const buffer = mmap(NULL, bytes, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
    return 1;
  }

  struct rusage statistics;
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &statistics);
  const long start_faults = statistics.ru_minflt + statistics.ru_majflt;

  printf("                          Address Touches Faults Extra Faults\n");

  for (unsigned long byte = 0; byte < bytes; byte += page_size) {
    buffer[byte] = 15;

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &statistics);
    const long current_faults = statistics.ru_minflt + statistics.ru_majflt - start_faults;
    const unsigned long touches = byte / page_size + 1;
    
    print_4kib_page(buffer + byte);
    printf("%7lu%7ld%13ld\n", touches, current_faults, clamp(current_faults, touches));
  }
}

The output on my system (Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, 6.8.0-48-generic) is as follows:
                          Address Touches Faults Extra Faults
     0| 254| 288| 422|   0|    0|       1      9            8
     0| 254| 288| 422|   1|    0|       2     13           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   2|    0|       3     14           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   3|    0|       4     15           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   4|    0|       5     16           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   5|    0|       6     17           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   6|    0|       7     18           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   7|    0|       8     19           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   8|    0|       9     20           11
     0| 254| 288| 422|   9|    0|      10     21           11
     ...
     0| 254| 288| 429| 502|    0|    4087   4098           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 503|    0|    4088   4099           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 504|    0|    4089   4100           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 505|    0|    4090   4101           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 506|    0|    4091   4102           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 507|    0|    4092   4103           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 508|    0|    4093   4104           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 509|    0|    4094   4105           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 510|    0|    4095   4106           11
     0| 254| 288| 429| 511|    0|    4096   4107           11

On the first touch, there are 8 extra faults, which seems to indicate that the OS is pre-faulting the last-level page tables. Each page of actual memory touched results in exactly one additional page fault.
For the second touch, the number of extra faults unexpectedly increases from 8 to 11. This suggests 3 additional page faults occurred, but I don't understand why. After the second touch, the number of extra faults stays at 11. Why are there 3 additional page faults on the second memory touch?

Your C program's process is not alone. The C runtime library causes page faults. A better way is to silently accumulate your statistics in a preallocated array while you measure, and do the printfs when the array fills up, and you restart the whole thing.

@waltinator You're right, it was the C runtime library. Doing all the printing at the end gives a clear 1:1 relationship between the number of pages touched and the resulting page faults. Thank you!
